# Mat palette - create on the fly

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-theming

The user needs to select a 3 colours from a colour picker (primary, warn, and accent).

Then in the second system I need to set those as the Angular Material theming.

As I am fetching those colours from the database and receiving from an observable, would there be a way of changing the theming based on those 3 colours coming from the database using Typescript? Or any other solution?

I tried many things already.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar recently and it's not trivial.

The way to go would require the use of [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

The trick is to define the material palette with a set of css custom properties.

[Cf the doc](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#palettes), a palette is made of 10 + 10 values.

```
$my-palette: (
 50: --primary-50,
 100: --primary-100,
 200: --primary-200,
 // ... continues to 900
 contrast: (
   50: --primary-constrast-50,
   100: --primary-constrast-100,
   200: --primary-constrast-200,
   // ... continues to 900
 )
);
```

Then you can define a mat palette with : `$my-primary : mat.define-palette($my-palette)`

Which is then used in the theme :

```
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
   warn: $my-warn,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
 density: 0,
));
```

Comment: great answer! same aproach worked for me on angular14, but did you check if it works on angular 15+? they've updated material components and I am not 100% sure that new components aren't using some tricky scss math, that would require pallete values to be values, not some tricky things like css custom properties

Comment: Well, I kinda did not understand how to use this to solve my issue. Cos all of this that you said is in css, right?

Because as I said, I need to change the theme based on what the user will choose in your backoffice system. So the user will pick up 3 random colours from the colour picker, I then need to use this in another system to set the theme, based on what that used has chosen. And these 3 colours in my case will be stored in the DB, I will fetch it in my angular controller, then change the theme.

Comment: Yeah sorry the missing bit is that you can set the css variables at runtime with Js !